# Is an open ball also closed as it satisfies the condition of a closed ball?

Tags: general-topology

An open ball at center point x and radius r is

$B_r(x) = \{y | d(x, y) < r \}$

where as a closed ball at center point x and radius r is

$\bar B_r(x) = \{y | d(x, y) \le r \}$.

This means that $B_r(x) \subseteq \bar B_r(x)$ but also means that all the points y in the open ball also satisfy the definition of the closed ball. Does this imply that an open ball is also a closed one?

Comment: No, this implies that an open ball is a subset of a closed one

Answer (score 2):

Compare these two statements:

> 1. This means that $B_r(x) \subseteq \bar B_r(x)$ but also means that all
>    the points y in *the open ball* also satisfy the definition of *the
>    closed ball*. Does this imply that *an open ball* is also *a closed one*?
> 2. This means that $\mathbb N \subseteq \mathbb Z$ but also means that all
>    the points y in *the positive integers* also satisfy the definition of *the
>    integers*. Does this imply that *the set of positive integers* is also *the set of integers*?

What you are confusing is that terms open and closed refer to sets as a whole, not its members. In English you could forgive someone for saying: "All New Yorkers live in America. Therefore, New York is America." But, this is just kind of liberty natural languages allow (where we really should have said "New York is *in* America") that mathematics does not, for the obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The open ball does not contain the boundary of the closed ball. For the open ball you have $d(x,y) < r$ and for the closed Ball you have $d(x,y)\leq r$ and $<$ is not the same as $\leq$.